# Makefile CreateProcess(NULL, echo Executing all complete!, ...) failed

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, makefile

I used the extension "C/C++ Project Generator" in vscode to create a c++ project. When I input "make run", the errors come:

```
PS D:\vscodeProjects\OpenGL> make run
g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -g -Iinclude -o output\main.exe src/main.o  -Llib
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, echo Executing all complete!, ...) failed.
make (e=2):
Makefile:68: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Here are the makefile:

```
OUTPUT  := output
MAIN    := main.exe
all: $(OUTPUT) $(MAIN)
    @echo Executing 'all' complete!
```

Could you help me to find the solution?

Comment: please use a minimal example, removing whatever is not needed to reproduce. Add the exact command line you used.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I have changed the question

Comment: You are apparently running on Windows, and shell you're using doesn't have access to a separate "echo" program so it fails.